# Spring Form submission with Timestamp

Tags: spring, timestamp

Currently, I'm having a timestamp field in an object. I will be using this object as my form attribute.

```
class public MyBean {
   @NotNull
   private long id;
   private String name;
   private Timestamp myDate;
}
```

Whenever I submit the spring form, the date never get pass down to the myDate field. It always be NULL. I tried to ask Mr.Google and I saw a few person facing the similar issue. However, there is no concrete conclusion from their posts.

1. Some recommend to use LocalDateTime/LocalDate instead of timestamp.
2. Some recommend to use PropertyEditor to parse the date manually.

But, I'm kind of not being satisfy with the given answers as the posts are quite old.

Any expert kindly enough to share his/her expertise at here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: search timestamp issue to judge before LocalDate not concrete solution.

Comment: Can you post your code where the object is created and/or controller receives the data? Have you tried debugging to see where the null value appears?

Comment: Hi everyone, sorry for the late reply as I was kind of busy recently. Anyway, previously I'm getting NULL for my timestamp because my client side was submitting Date (without time) only. Hence, the mapping failed since timestamp required both date/time. But I already solved this by implement a custom property editor to convert the input date to timestamp. :)

Thanks guys for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.time.LocalDateTime`, `java.util.Date` or a timestamp in miliseconds (as a `long`), Depending on how your frontend handles things. Heck, you can even pass a String in a `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format and parse it to a Date object. However, your NPE might be appearing elsewhere, it is hard to tell without any code apart from that POJO.